# Calling Jython module from python

Tags: python, jython

i was wondering if there is a way to call monkeyrunner module which is a jython module via a IDLE Python, which is C.

I would like to monkeyrunner to send touch commands to my device and quite simply i was able to achieve that, and i was using SIMPLECV on IDLE python for images recognition.

However, i am unable to merge the 2 together as they use different ENV

Comment: You can use pydev in Eclipse . Choose jython run .I use jython env to run monkeyrunner

Comment: Try [Pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/).